# Access to Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

On my VM I get the following error while trying to download a file to the bucket:

```
username@instance-1:~$ gsutil -u absolute-bison-99999 cp gs://file.sam gs://username_bucket_1 
AccessDeniedException: 403 9999-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
username@instance-1:~$
```

In my IAM I have the following roles for 9999-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. Why is it still not allowing access?

```
Editor
Owner
Storage Admin
Storage Object Admin
Viewer
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states:

```
9999-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access
```

Can you check IAM roles for that particular storage bucket, please?

For example, IAM roles that a service account has in one project, may not be enough for working with resources from another project.

Comment: I only have one project. For the bucket I have: Storage Admin; Storage Object Admin

Comment: solved the problem by typing in the VM: gcloud auth login